# Why does this UTF-16 HTTP response end up as UTF-8 when in the resulting Stream?

Tags: c#, encoding, http-headers, content-type, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an issue where a service is returning me a HTTP Header:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-16
```

When this is serialised by C# this ends up in a UTF-8 stream, which obviously breaks. It seems that utf-16 is a valid encoding in [IANA spec](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml). So why is this code not working?

```cs
System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient ...;
using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
{
   //response.Content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "utf-16"
   using (var responseContentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
   {
       using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
       {
          //streamReader.CurrentEncoding.BodyName returns utf-8 here?! 
       }
   }
}
```

so initially the `response` seems fine but then once it gets as far as the `streamReader` it seems to of reverted back to utf-8. Why?

Comment: It seems like you're expecting the `StreamReader` (which does the conversion from individual bytes into a string) to determine the encoding from the stream alone.

Comment: If the content is small enough, use `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` -- that has the smarts to use the right encoding. If you use a `StreamReader`, you're just giving it a `Stream` with no information on the encoding to use

Comment: When a client and server connect a negotiation occurs where the webpage headers on the server and the headers int the request are used to determine the common mode of operation.   In some cases the server ignores the clients headers and other cases the server will support the mode in the client headers.  For example a server may support both English and French.  So the server uses the headers from the client to determine the homepage in the correct language.  Every Server is different.  So did you include the charset in the request.  Some cases the language determines the encoding.

Comment: HttpContent uses [this logic](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs,179) to determine the encoding of the response when you use `ReadAsStringAsync()`. If you use `ReadAsStreamAsync()`, then of course none of that code is run.

Comment: Yes @canton7 that was one of the things that confused me, I guess I expected the stream to "have the smarts" too. Oh well

Comment: @Liam A stream is just a collection of bytes, nothing more. There's no concept of an encoding, as any old arbitrary stream probably doesn't even represent text!

Comment: @canton7 if you could write that up as an answer I would accept, or I can just delete this, whatever really. Got my answer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the encoding the StreamReader should use in the constructor.
In your case it should look like this:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode, true))
{
  // The reader should read the Stream with UTF-16 here
}
```

Comment: That's not really what I'm after, this could return utf-8 or utf-16. What I want to know is why isn't the StreamReader honouring the encoding in the HTTP response

Comment: @Liam because the StreamReader doesn't *know* anything about the HTTP response. You haven't told it anything! All you've given it is a collection of bytes

Comment: @Liam the StreamReader uses UTF-8 per default if no other encoding is specified.
But you could just read the Encoding from the response header and switch the reader encoding accordingly